# How to install Functional Icons after version React.js >= 16.8.0

Tags: reactjs

I want to install UI material icons from: https://v4.mui.com/getting-started/installation/

It says: "Please note that react >= 16.8.0 and react-dom >= 16.8.0 are peer dependencies."
For the installation.

I experienced that `npm install @material-ui/core` and `npm install @material-ui/icons`

Results in the error messages, what happened after version 16.8.0 of React.js? And how to install?

Thank you in advance.

Some extra info on me:
I am learning to code atm. I would like to build something front and back-end.
Learn JS and learn to work with a database. Following allong a tutorial to get the 'feel' for it and how to work with the MERN stack.